# Panel Data Regression, ADF Stationarity Test in R

Tags: r, panel-data, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, plm

I am conducting a fixed effects regression with balanced quarterly paneldata.

`plm(MOD.WITHIN, data=pdata, model = "within", effect= "individual")`

The dependent variable is gov. bond yield of country i.
Independent variables are several country-specific variables and country invariant variables (global/cross-sectional invariant) like VIX index, US term premium and US expected future policy rate, which do not differ across individuals but across time.

`yield_it ~ X_it + vix_t + ustermp_t + usexp_t`

I already tested for the appropriate model (fixed effects) and tested for cross-sectional dependence (Pesaran/Breusch-Pagan)

`pcdtest(MOD.WITHIN, test = c("lm")); pcdtest(MOD.WITHIN, test = c("cd"))`

and serial correlation (Breusch-Godfrey) which both seem to apply.

`pbgtest(MOD.WITHIN)`

Hence, I tested for stationarity i.e. unit-roots for all my variables. Since the above tests suggest Cross-sectional Interdependence and Serial correlation, I used the ADF test "ips" from Im, Pesaran, and Shin (2003); pmax 4 since I use quarterly data:

`purtest(pdata$USEXP, lags="AIC", exo = "intercept", pmax = 4, test = "ips")`

**Thus my question:**

Can I use this ADF test above for my cross-sectional variables (VIX etc.) too? Or should I use another Test (levinlin, adf.test), because the result below seems to be off.

```
Exogenous variables: Individual Intercepts 
Automatic selection of lags using AIC: 3 - 3 lags (max: 4)
statistic (Wtbar): -2.932 
p-value: 0.002 

   lags obs        rho      trho    p.trho    mean    var
BR    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
CL    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
CO    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
HN    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
ID    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
KO    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
MX    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
MY    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
PH    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
PO    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
RU    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
SA    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
TH    3  58 -0.1201754 -2.216354 0.2003637 -1.4866 0.8054
```

I would appreciate it if someone can help me. Cheers

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "results seems to be off"?

Comment: Since Cross-sectional Interdependence is present, I used these special versions of the ADF test. But the VIX for example, is it cross-sectional dependent if it's just the same for all entities? I can imagine variables like Business Cycle (GDP%) can be, but if a variable is defined as a unit invariant variable does this test give accurate results?